# FFmpeg check channels of a 7.1 audio for silence

Tags: audio, ffmpeg, codec, aac, ffprobe

This is a follow-up question from my previous question asked [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54613952/ffmpeg-check-audio-channels-for-silence/54615874?noredirect=1#comment96029489_54615874), where I needed to look for silence within a specific audio track. Here is the `ffmpeg` life-saver solution where helps to get some metadata:

```
ffmpeg -i file -map 0:a:1 -af astats -f null -
```

But I have other type of input `.mp4` files where they have one single track of `8` (i.e. 7.1) audio channels. Apparently these files are transcoded from an original file (somehow the 4 track stereos are squished into these files). Now similar to my previous, I need to know if the original file was 2-channel stereo or 5.1 (6) channel.

How to know if a specific channel of an audio track (say `Center` channel) is silent/mute, possibly using `ffmpeg`? [Here](https://www.dropbox.com/s/a417r4xpykbf2m3/test2.mp4?dl=0) is a sample `.mp4` file.

Comment: Replace `0:a:1` with `0:a:0` to analyze the first stream.

Comment: Thanks. Is there any way to see only output of specific channel? say `Center`? I also don't know the layout, which # is which.

Comment: ffmpeg's layout may not be [reliable](https://video.stackexchange.com/q/23140/1871) for MOV/MP4. In any case, something like channelsplit to isolate the channel, or grep the astats readout.

Comment: @Gyan wondering why the result of your command is different from the answer. Your command doesn't say `-inf` for Channel #3. But the command in the answer says `FC` is silence.

Comment: `-inf` is for perfect digital silence. Channel #3 has a few stray samples: `Min level: -0.000007 Max level: 0.000006`. silencedetect has a threshold and any volume below that threshold is registered as silence. `-90db` or lower is effectively digital silence.

Comment: ummm I see. Maybe I can just take Ch#4 which shows as `RMS level dB: -inf` for empty (I assume this never will be -inf for full 7.1 contents). Or just get `<-100db` for ch#3. Are my assumptions valid?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to determine? Audible silence, then -60 or lower. is sufficient. Perfect null-sampled track, then -inf.

Comment: To detect full silence. I was expecting a digital silence on FC on my sample test, but looks like it is not digital. I think it is fine to consider it as digital.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use the [channelsplit](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#channelsplit) filter to split the audio channels and run [silencedetect](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#silencedetect) on each.

Example:

`ffmpeg -i test2.mp4 -filter_complex "[0:a]channelsplit=channel_layout=7.1:channels=FC[fc];[fc]silencedetect" -f null /dev/null`

You can find more on audio channel manipulation here:
https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/AudioChannelManipulation

Comment: What I got was this: `[silencedetect @ 0000024c44b02700] silence_start: 0
frame= 1891 fps=0.0 q=-0.0 Lsize=N/A time=00:01:03.10 bitrate=N/A speed=73.8x
video:990kB audio:5916kB subtitle:0kB other streams:0kB global headers:0kB muxing overhead: unknown
[silencedetect @ 0000024c44b02700] silence_end: 63.104 | silence_duration: 63.104`. So what does it mean?

Comment: You got 63.104s of silence

Comment: I need to know if it is fully silence. Any ways? (like my command in question, a metadata says `-inf` which is what I look for)

Comment: Compare `silence_duration` with the duration of the audio stream?

Comment: Yeah..that can be a dirty solution. Is that `time=00:01:03.10` the total stream duration?

Comment: Btw, FC is the center channel. Right? How to know which channel # it is?

Comment: wondering why the result of your command is different from one in my question. Ch#3 in `ffmpeg -i file -map 0:a:0 -af astats -f null -` doesn't say silent. But your command says FC is silent. Can you verify please?

Comment: *Compare silence_duration with the duration of the audio stream* --> astats obviates that by allowing to accumulating statistics over the whole stream. Of course, there's also volumedetect.

Answer (score 1):

There is also the [astats](https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#astats-1) filter which can be used to detect silent tracks/channels.

This i what it outputs for the channel 4 of the suggest test file, which appears indeed to be perfectly silent.

```
ffmpeg -i "$in" -vn -sn -dn -map 0:a -af "astats=measure_overall=none" -f null -
```

> ```
> ...
> [Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x6beed00] Channel: 4
> [Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x6beed00] DC offset: 0.000000
> [Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x6beed00] Min level: 0.000000
> [Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x6beed00] Max level: 0.000000
> [Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x6beed00] Min difference: 0.000000
> [Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x6beed00] Max difference: 0.000000
> [Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x6beed00] Mean difference: 0.000000
> [Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x6beed00] RMS difference: 0.000000
> [Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x6beed00] Peak level dB: -inf
> [Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x6beed00] RMS level dB: -inf
> [Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x6beed00] RMS peak dB: -inf
> [Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x6beed00] RMS trough dB: -inf
> [Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x6beed00] Crest factor: 1.000000
> [Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x6beed00] Flat factor: -inf
> [Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x6beed00] Peak count: 6057984
> [Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x6beed00] Bit depth: 0/0
> [Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x6beed00] Dynamic range: -inf
> [Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x6beed00] Zero crossings: 0
> [Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x6beed00] Zero crossings rate: 0.000000
> [Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x6beed00] Number of NaNs: 0
> [Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x6beed00] Number of Infs: 0
> [Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x6beed00] Number of denormals: 0
> [Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x6beed00] Channel: 5
> ...
> ```

Something like this would show an overview of all channels:

```
ffmpeg -i "$in" -vn -sn -dn -map 0:a -af "astats=measure_overall=none" -f null - 2>&1 \
| egrep 'Channel|(Max|Peak) level'
```

> ```
> [Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7567d00] Channel: 1
> [Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7567d00] Max level: 0.978271
> [Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7567d00] Peak level dB: -0.190818
> [Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7567d00] Channel: 2
> [Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7567d00] Max level: 0.978271
> [Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7567d00] Peak level dB: -0.190818
> [Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7567d00] Channel: 3
> [Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7567d00] Max level: 0.000006
> [Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7567d00] Peak level dB: -103.162709
> [Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7567d00] Channel: 4
> [Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7567d00] Max level: 0.000000
> [Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7567d00] Peak level dB: -inf
> [Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7567d00] Channel: 5
> [Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7567d00] Max level: 0.000006
> [Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7567d00] Peak level dB: -103.162709
> [Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7567d00] Channel: 6
> [Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7567d00] Max level: 0.000006
> [Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7567d00] Peak level dB: -103.162709
> [Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7567d00] Channel: 7
> [Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7567d00] Max level: 0.978271
> [Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7567d00] Peak level dB: -0.190818
> [Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7567d00] Channel: 8
> [Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7567d00] Max level: 0.978271
> [Parsed_astats_0 @ 0x7567d00] Peak level dB: -0.190818
> ```

Comment: Looks great. Thanks!

Comment: None of above codes worked for me! Help please.